# Extract XY lines of specific orientation python

Tags: python, numpy, gis

now I have a new dataset that the first 2 columns are X and Y points (in general they represent locations. the data file are pretty large, and for initial data analysis I need to extract specific lines (or close to line data) - is there any way to tell numpy (or python, or pandas) to extract this specific data set - attached is an example, which is simplified and the data are pretty rounded (which is not the case with the real data) but will clearly show what I need:

**Example** *EDIT**

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
X = list(range(45))*3 
Y = list(range(1, 91, 2)) + list(range(20, 65, 1)) + list(range(1, 136, 3))   
XY = zip(X, Y)
XYarray = np.array(XY).reshape(135, 2)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.plot(XYarray[:,0], XYarray[:,1], 'ro') #all data
plt.plot(XYarray[0:44,0], XYarray[0:44,1], 'b*') #first line to be teste
#plt.plot(XYarray[45:90,0], XYarray[45:90,1], 'g*') #other lines of interest
#plt.plot(XYarray[91:135,0], XYarray[91:135,1], 'gx') #otherline of ineters
fig.show()
```

all my data lie within an arbitrary XY array (surface spatial data) -I need to extract lines availlable; for example I want to extract only the uncommented blue star line  - and then move the next ones (currently commented in the code
Keep in mind that my actual data are not that regular
Hope that helps

Comment: I dont understand what you need

Comment: @JoranBeasley I need to create anew file, that contains all the data that are highlighted by the ellipse - see edit

Comment: @Dimitris are you picking up form a previous question? I don't understand either. What do you mean by "extract"? Extract in what form? Put yourself in the shoes of a complete stranger (who knows how to program) and think if your question would make sense to them.

Comment: @MrE I understand it was vague, so I added some info - hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes I get it now. What I would do is convert from the `Ellipse` parameters to [the standard form of the ellipse equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations), evaluate the left hand side for all your points (you can do this in a vectorized way) and then select the points where the left hand side is `< 1`. This is written as a comment because I need to make dinner and don't have time to give more details!

Comment: One more comment to say that the link I provided is only valid for axis-aligned ellipses. I don't have a perfect resource on how convert between the angle/width/height and the general equation / quadratic form matrix but I can try and write this up later in the week if you need. It'll basically look like `A = R D R^t`, where `R` is a [2D rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), `D` is a diagonal matrix with elements something like `[1/width^2, 1/height^2]` and your values to threshold are given by `XYarray^t A XYarray`

Comment: @MrE thanks for the comments - it looks like they are taking me towards the right direction - I have to think about your solution, since my math appear to be way weaker than yours (not to mention my coding skills) but any piece of code gets me closer to a solution; what your previous comment made me think is pretty similar to what I believe you wrote here, where I would rotate my whole dataset - around the lowest x,y point, and always extract the vertical line - I do not know how to get there, but this is my plan of moving forward

Comment: @MrE also the line of interest does not have to be identified by an eclipse, I used this to highlight the points - in general I need points that fall into a (relatively) straight line in any given orientation

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't like these long discussions in the comments it seems. You should re-write the question to reflect your actual problem if it really is the line detection. I suggest you also add a screenshot of a plot of your actual data and draw on it the lines you would want to be detected.

Comment: Possible typo: the first point that you want in `line1` should be [20, 0], correct?

Comment: Since you say the ellipse was added just to illustrate the desired points, it is not clear what distinguishes this set of points from many other possible lines that could be drawn through points in your data.  But you do say in a comment "I need points that fall into a (relatively) straight line in any given orientation".  So the orientation is given?  How? As a slope?  An angle?  Even with an orientation, the problem seems underdetermined--there are several collections of points that could be chosen in your example.

Comment: I just reread the title of the question, and I see that it says "specific orientation".  So the orientation should be part of the input of the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for catching the typo - I will update; specific orientation I mean, any line I might be interested in - I will edit the input file to show that clearly

Comment: "any line I might be interested in" is still vague.  How should the line that you are interested in be specified as input to an algorithm?  A given slope and intercept?  A given point and direction?  Something else?  Once such an input is given, do you simply want all the points that are "close" to that line (for some definition of "close")?